# Datatables - How to stop the server side draw event when adding new data to table

Tags: datatables

I've table with data loaded from server side, as there will be huge datasets I've to go for server side loading.

```
var table = $('#table').DataTable({ 
     "processing": true, 
     "serverSide": true, 
     "ajax" : { "url": "...", "type": "POST" }, 
     "columns": [ { 
        "orderable": false, 
        "data" : 'id', 
        "render" : function( data, type, meta ) 
                                 { return '..'; }
    },
    {
        "orderable": true,
        "data"     : ".."
    },
    {
        "orderable": true,
        "data"     : "..",
        "className": 'right-align'
    },
    {
        "orderable": true,
        "data"     : "..",
        "className": 'right-align'
    },
    {
        "orderable": false,
        "data"     : 'id',
        "defaultContent": "",
        "className": 'center-align',
        "render"   : function(data, type, meta) {

            return '..';
        }
    },
    {
        "orderable": false, // flags
        "data"     : {
            'inserted' : 'inserted',
            'deleted'  : 'deleted'
        },
        "defaultContent": "",
        "className"    : 'center-align',
        "render"   : '..'
        }
    }
],
'order': [
    [1, "asc"]
],
"language": {
    "lengthMenu": '..'
}
```

});

And I've to provide filtering capability for this table ( there are few checkboxes which will trigger the post request on change) so I'm sending the filters to backend and it gives me new dataset.

```
$.post(url, { 'filters' : data} , function(collection){
     table.clear().draw();
     table.rows.add(JSON.parse(collection));
     table.columns.adjust().draw();
});
```

It's firing total 3 requests, one for the post request and two draw request ( As I'm drawing twice).

According to server side processing, each draw of the table will result in a new Ajax request being made to get the required data. Now this data is overriding the data which I got from filters.

**How can I draw the table with new dataset? Or How can I stop those server side ajax requests from triggering.**

I tried preDrawCallback, which is shuting the entire draw functionality.

```
$('#table').dataTable( {
  "preDrawCallback": function( settings ) {
     return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ajax.data](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) to specify a custom parameter sent to the server, see one of the ways to do it below.

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "data.json",
        "data": function (d){
            d.example_select = $('#example-select').val();
        }
    }
});
```

`ajax.data` callback function will be called every time DataTables requests data from the server.

To reload data from the server after your filter changes, you can use [ajax.reload()](http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload%28%29) function, for example:

```
$('#example-select').on('change', function(){
    $('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload(); 
});
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wx1odf4k/2/) for demonstration.

Comment: The processing( i.e paging, ordering, searching) is done by different route and filtering is done by different route. So I did used the ajax.data to send the filters to backend and on every change I'm setting the ajax url `table.ajax.url(url).load()` ( it'll load the data from new url ) and if zero checkboxes are checked then I'm setting back the original url.

@Gyrocode.com Thanks for help